# Is IQueryable safe to use to move data in my application?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app that uses EF Core to access data and I have a method that lists all records of a table based on some filters and returns them as an `IQueryable<MyObject>`. The thing is I need to access the results of this `IQueryable` more than one time with foreach loops, so for every loop I make is it hitting the database again and again?

I thought that after the first query was executed in the database the results would be cached in memory but I0'm really not sure, can someone please help me?

This is my method that lists the records:

```
public async Task<IQueryable<Registro>> List(FiltroRegistros filtro)
{
    IQueryable<Registro> query = _context.Set<Registro>();

    if (filtro.AtivadoDesativado == null || (bool)filtro.AtivadoDesativado)
        query = query.Where(x => x.DataExclusao == null);

    if (filtro.Nf != null)
        query = query.Where(x => x.EmitiuNotaFiscal == filtro.Nf);

    if (filtro.Status != null)
        query = query.Where(x => x.Status == filtro.Status);

    if (filtro.Pagamento != null)
        query = query.Where(x => x.PagamentoRecebido == filtro.Pagamento);

    if (filtro.Nf != null)
        query = query.Where(x => x.EmitiuNotaFiscal == filtro.Nf);

    return await Task.FromResult(query);
}
```

This is one of the operations I do with the results:

```
public async Task<byte[]> GerarExcel(IQueryable<Registro> registros)
{
    using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        IXLWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Controle");
        int currentRow = 1;

        #region Header
        worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 1).Value = "PROJETO";
        worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 2).Value = "TIPO";
        worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 3).Value = "WWC";
        worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 4).Value = "HORAS";
        worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 5).Value = "FEITO EM";
        worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 6).Value = "VALOR (R$)";
        #endregion

        #region Body
        foreach (Registro registro in registros)
        {
            currentRow++;
            worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 1).Value = registro.Projeto;
            worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 2).Value = registro.Tipo;
            worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 3).Value = registro.WWC;
            worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 4).Value = registro.HORAS;
            worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 5).Value = registro.FeitoEm;
            worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 6).Value = registro.Valor;
        }
        #endregion

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            workbook.SaveAs(stream);
            byte[] content = stream.ToArray();

            return await Task.FromResult(content);
        }
    }
}
```

I also use Automapper to map this `IQueryable` to a `List` of my view model class:

```
IQueryable<Registro> registros = await _registroService.List(filtro);

model.Registros = _mapper.Map<List<RegistroViewModel>>(registros);
```

Comment: Could you show your code? Welcome to S.O. please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i added my code, sorry for the poor question

Comment: By the way, your List method is not really async - Task. FromResult returns synchronously. Better would be `return await query.ToListAsync();` - but that changes the return type to List instead of IQueryable

Answer (score 0):

Looping a `IQueryable<T>` does query the DB exactly once:

```cs
IQueryable<Registro> registros = await _registroService.List(filtro);
foreach (Registro r in registros) {
    Console.WriteLine(r);
}
```

This queries the DB when the loop is initiated and then pulls the records. The DB will execute one query.

This is explained in [Query Execution / Deferred query execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution#deferred-query-execution).

You can also use a profiler (e.g. the SQL-Server Profiler) to see what the DB is doing. Or you can use the [Logging and Interception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/) mechanisms of EF Core.